# Find questions without answers or comments and not on hold/closed?

Tags: discussion

I visit salesforce.stackexchange from time to time, but often only have a few minutes.  I most often check out the Unanswered queue.  Often I see questions that have no answers but great comments, and the question is getting the desired attention, and I can't really add anything to the process.

Is there a way to see questions with no answers AND no comments?  These are the questions that could truly use some attention.

Comment: I found StackExchange Data Explorer, which appears to get us there.  See here: http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/520906/closed-questions-without-comments -- when you run query it will get a list of posts without answers or comments.  Just need to exclude closed or on hold questions, and this will be ready!

Comment: That's awesome! Please post that as an answer to your question! I've often wanted exactly the same thing. It's unfortunate that NoAnswers queue is first sorted by votes then, by date descending (think that's the correct description), so it takes a while to get to the recent unanswered questions that haven't received any attention. That's something we could definitely use to help get those questions the attention they deserve. Kudos for asking this question.

Comment: Not quite done yet @crmprogdev, if I can get it to actually exclude on hold items, (or someone else can) I'll accept that answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This gets us there:
http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/521516/closed-questions-without-comments

Only the first item in the list shows as Closed, the rest seem to be ok and behaving.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the `Advanced Search Tips`, which do not contain any comment filters:

```
tags             [tag]
exact            "words here"
author           user:1234
                 user:me (yours)
score            score:3 (3+)
                 score:0 (none)
answers          answers:3 (3+)
                 answers:0 (none)
                 isaccepted:yes
                 hasaccepted:no
                 inquestion:1234
views            views:250
sections         title:apples
                 body:"apples oranges"
url              url:"*.example.com"
favorites        infavorites:mine
                 infavorites:1234
status           closed:yes
                 duplicate:no
                 migrated:no
                 wiki:no
                 deleted:no
types            is:question
                 is:answer
exclude          -[tag]
                 -apples
```

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible, then?

Comment: @Ray That's my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I just modified the query you referenced in your comments and have saved it. It's titled [Open questions without Answers or Comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/521043/open-questions-without-answers-or-comments?opt.withExecutionPlan=true). Oddly, the first one that it returned showed as being on Hold. I don't know if that's because the database hasn't been updated to reflect that or because there's an additional field that's been omitted, but the remainder of what's being returned seems to be open and without comments. You can always "fork" the query and try tweaking it further which is what I did to get the above results from the original query that you'd provided the link to.

Comment: Looks like you only changed ClosedDate IS NOT NULL to ClosedDate IS NULL, but yeah I don't think "on hold" means ClosedDate is NULL in that scenario.  From what I can tell, we need to subquery the PostHistory table and exclude the "on hold" post history type.

Comment: My sql-fu is weak

Comment: My sql-fu is Null. LOL! There's a tool that converts between soql and sql. It's called Cloudingo Studio from Symphonic Source and it's free. Am a bit busy at the moment, but will try to look at it a bit later to see if I can improve on the query. Closed is definitely not the same as being on hold. I believe you're correct that a subquery might be in order.

Comment: Posted this in an answer below: http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/521516/closed-questions-without-comments